# Bootstrap Dynamic table filter working when using in php file but working in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to populate a bootstrap dynamic table through php, but the filter and search are not working. I have hosted the .js and .css files locally. My php code is as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Reports</title>
        <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensions/DynTables/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensions/DynTables/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensions/DynTables/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensions/DynTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
        });
    });
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../Extensions/DynTables/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../Extensions/DynTables/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="../Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
    <link href="../Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Reports</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Reports
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Form No</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>System</th>
                                            <th>Administrator</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?PHP
                                            $myquery="select * from Table_1";   
                                            $fetched=sqlsrv_query($conn,$myquery) ; 
                                            if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
                                            while($res=sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                                            {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr class="even gradeA">
                                            <td><?PHP echo $res['ID']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?PHP echo $res['Form_No']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?PHP echo $res['System']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?PHP echo $res['Administrator']; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?PHP } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The HTML Code is as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Reports</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="Extensions/DynTables/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="Extensions/DynTables/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
    <link href="Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Reports</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Reports
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Form No</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>System</th>
                                            <th>Administrator</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>4247</td>
                                            <td>Per-2015-08-05-4247 </td>
                                            <td>Test</td>
                                            <td class="center"></td>
                                            <td class="center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="even gradeC">
                                            <td>4248</td>
                                            <td>Nar-2015-08-05-4248</td>
                                            <td>Test1</td>
                                            <td class="center"></td>
                                            <td class="center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeA">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                                            <td class="center">5.5</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="Extensions/DynTables/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="Extensions/DynTables/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="Extensions/DynTables/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script src="Extensions/DynTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Extensions/DynTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The folder is right, as the css is working. Only the filter and search isn't working. I have attached snips of the code in html and in php.

**In HTML**
[image]

**In PHP**
[image]

What could be the issue? Where have I gone wrong? Would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Where is the body of your html?

Comment: @LiamSorsby Edited the question and added it.

Comment: Have you tested the query works and outputs data? Also, you don't need the classes on the tr. The javascript should automatically add these in.

Comment: One can infer from your screenshots that your PHP has no data in the table (because we don't seen any text poking out your cropped image). Is this the case?

Comment: @LiamSorsby Yes It does. I am getting the data. Only the search and filter aren't working.

Comment: Have you tried adding the display class to the form?

Comment: @apokryfos no There is data, I didn't include it in the screenshot.

Comment: @LiamSorsby which display class?

Comment: @ST1602 I assume you are using the following library: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @ST1602 if you look in the initialisation code aswel I imagine the part to enable searching and filtering may have been disabled.

Comment: @apokryfos no errors

Comment: @LiamSorsby no I am using a different one. and no I haven't disabled it. I am using the same libraries for the html and php code, it works with the HTML but not with the php code. Also the one in HTML is hardcoded

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well? The one that's working properly.

Comment: @apokryfos done :)

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that.. Not working..

Comment: I can't for the life of me reproduce this. Can you just inspect the HTML source on the page generated via PHP to make sure everything corresponds to what you've expected and that it looks like the HTML?

Comment: @apokryfos it does.. I have cross checked.. only not sure where to  put the javascript source in the php files. Maybe that would make a difference

Comment: @ST1602 the only important thing is to have jquery and datatables included before the `$(document).ready...` because you are using symbols that need to be defined there. Other than that it doesn't matter where you put the scripts (because document.ready is supposed to take care of the waiting before it initializes the datatable).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114846/discussion-between-st1602-and-apokryfos).